# Testing a massive use of method with @Cacheable

Tags: java, hibernate, testing, ehcache

i am trying to solve an issue from work that consists in a method that is called several times in production and breaks, here is the interface's method:

```
@Cacheable("CategoryDao.findAllLocale")
  Set<Category> findAllLocale(String locale);
```

And here is the implementation:

```
public Set<Category> findAllLocale(final String locale) {
    final Set<Category> localeCategories = this.findAllLocaleRootCategories(locale);
    for (final Category rootCategory : localeCategories) {
      final Set<Category> localeChildCategories = this.findAllLocaleByParent(locale, rootCategory.getCatId());
      rootCategory.setCategories(localeChildCategories);
    }
    return localeCategories;
  }
```

Is a simple DAO method but the problem is that returns a lot of data and in server productions throws this exception:

```
01-01-15 10:09:47:984 - {ERROR} categories.GetAllCategoriesAction  - User:5007660771072025 - Unexpected exception executing the action
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.company.app.data.Category.categories, no session or session was closed
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:380)
```

I think that the exception is something about that the @Cacheable overloads, because the app runs a few hours and works fine but then crash and log that fragment, I want make a "massive" use of this test so i will know is that or something else, any suggestions?

PD: @Cacheable is from ehcache framework
PD2: Sorry for my english

Answer (score 0):

The issue comes from the fact that let Hibernate/JPA entities escape, making them live longer than the session they were attached to.
So the issue comes at a later point when you use one of them (from the cache but it may not even be directly related) and try to access a lazy loaded collection. And that last point fails because you are already outside of the bounds of your Hibernate/JPA session.

As a rule of thumb, you should not cache Hibernate/JPA entities.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I already solve the problem, but i do like to know how can i test that to recreate the exception on a test